# Sinon create stub instance - include protected properties

Tags: sinon

My question is how does one include protected properties when creating a stub instance.

In my jest test I have:

```
const sandbox = createSandbox();
let manager: SinonStubbedInstance<EntityManager>;
let repo: Repo;

beforeEach(() => {
    manager = sandbox.createStubInstance(EntityManager);
    repo = new Repo(manager);
});

afterEach(() => sandbox.restore());
```

Which is attempting to make a stub of:

```
export declare class EntityManager {

/**
 * Connection used by this entity manager.
 */
readonly connection: Connection;

/**
 * Custom query runner to be used for operations in this entity manager.
 * Used only in non-global entity manager.
 */
readonly queryRunner?: QueryRunner;

/**
 * Once created and then reused by en repositories.
 */
protected repositories: Repository<any>[];

/**
 * Plain to object transformer used in create and merge operations.
 */
.......
}
```

So I don't seem to be able to have readonly properties and protected properties included in the stub.

At the "repo = new Repo(manager);" line.
The above code yields the following exception:

```
Argument of type 'SinonStubbedInstance<EntityManager>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EntityManager'.
Property 'repositories' is missing in type 'SinonStubbedInstance<EntityManager>'.ts(2345)
```

Is there anyway to tell Sinon to include the properties?
Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. Just to explain the question a little bit using the above example. repo.doSomething(){entityManager.doIt()}; I just want to verify when repo.doSomething is called, entityManager.doIt() is called once

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with

```
repo = new Repo(manager as any);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what in your case the *Repo* does with the *EntityManager*, also it is not completely clear to me what you want to test here.. so based on this my answer is a bit generic, but maybe it points you in the right direction.

My idea: Maybe you should decouple them. I would approach it the following way:

1. Create a getter in the EntityManager that gets all repos, name it for example ***getRepos()***
2. Create a mocked array that contains some Repos... ***const mockedRepos;***
3. Mock the getter of the EntityManager with your stub instance returning your mocked data:

   **manager.getRepos.returns(mockedRepos);**

This way you don't need the protected repositories var in your test.

Comment: but still please think about what you want to achieve.. the EntityManager has the Repos, the Repo has the EntityManager, that seems to me like a strange concept, and somehow like a circular dependency.. stuff like that is always hard to test.

Comment: I didn't see anywhere that EntityManager has Repo. I am having a similar problem that the class I want to test has dependency injection. However, the parameter passed in(in the above case EntityManager) has private field that doesn't allow me to use sinonStubbedInstance. This private field doesn't really matter and can be anything